# Unable to stop sound and reset time

Tags: html, audio

I've got multiple instances of the html5 audio player on my page, and I use the jQuery fadeIn() fadeOut() to determine which song to play. When clicking a link to a different page, I have the current playing sound fade out volume, then stop, then reset progress to 0 seconds, then the page (along with the audio player) fades out and the new page fades in. I'm able to fade out the volume, but I can't reset the timer to 0 seconds for some reason:

```
<script>
$('.link').on('click', function(e){
    $('audio').currentTime = 0; /*reset timer*/
    displayNone();   /*fade out current page*/
    $(this.getAttribute("href")).fadeIn();  /*fade in target page*/
    stopAudio();
});

function displayNone() {
    $('.pagecontainer>div').fadeOut();
}

function stopAudio() { //fade out any current audio
    $('audio').animate({volume: 0}, 1000);
    setTimeout(function(){('audio').pause()},1000) /*stop audio after fading out volume*/
}

$('.sound').on('play', function () {
    $('audio').animate({volume: 1}, 100);  /*reset volume to 100% after clicking play button on player*/
});

</script>
....
....

<a href="page1" class="link">page 1</a>
<a href="page2" class="link">page 2</a>
<a href="page3" class="link">page 3</a>

<div class="pagecontainer">

    <div id="page1">
        <audio controls class="sound">
            <source src="music1.mp3"/>
            <source src="music1.ogg"/>
        </audio>
    </div>

    <div id="page2">
        <audio controls class="sound">
            <source src="music2.mp3"/>
            <source src="music2.ogg"/>
        </audio>
    </div>

    <div id="page3">
        <audio controls class="sound">
            <source src="music3.mp3"/>
            <source src="music3.ogg"/>
        </audio>
    </div>

</div>
```

For example:

- I'm currently on page1, with music1.mp3 playing for 10 seconds
- I click the link to page2 without stopping music1.mp3, and music1.mp3 volume fades out along with with page1, and page2 fades in successfully along with the music player for music2.mp3
- After let's say 10 seconds I click link for page1 to go back to page1
- The player for music1.mp3 is still playing (progress is 20 seconds) and haven't stopped, but now with zero volume

I don't get why music1.mp3 is not resetting its timer to 0 seconds and stopping fully.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Probably because `.currentTime` is not a jQuery method. Try something like `$('audio')[0].currentTime`.

Edit:

```
$('audio').each(function() {
    $(this).currentTime = 0;
});
```

Comment: Why the [0]? I've got 3 instances, wouldn't that only stop the first instance? What if I have the 2nd instance playing?

Comment: Nope that doesn't work either. =/ I've put what you wrote into either the stopAudio() function and the $('.link').on('click', function(e) function, neither works. Does ('audio').pause() work? Or is that not registering either?